# How to query custom post tye from specific category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

i need to display post from a custom post type but from one specific category, i use the code belowe but show me all post from all categories not just from 7.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat=7' , 'taxonomy' => 'tourcat');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo "TEST TEST TEST TEST";
        echo the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid argument for WP Query.

```
cat=7
```

Please read here about taxonomy queries, they should do what you require:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `$args` array simply holds an element that is `cat=7`, which is an incorrect way to pass arguments to the `WP_Query` constructor. Note that the issue is a little more obvious if you format your `$args` array with whitespace:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tour',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat=7' , /* Here is the problem */
    'taxonomy' => 'tourcat'
);
```

I believe your `$args` array should look like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tour',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'cat' => 7,
    'taxonomy' => 'tourcat'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This,

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat=7' , 'taxonomy' => 'tourcat');
```

Should instead be like,

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tourcat','field' => 'ID','terms' => '7' ) ));
```

Comment: Hi, perfect, work fine.  Now i need that 'terms' is e variable, because before this code i write an if statement.

To retrive all id categories from tourcat i tried this code but i can see just one id not all id.

$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tourcat', array("fields" => "all"));
foreach($term_list as $term_single) {
echo $term_single->term_id;
}

Ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Hi user3421040, glad that it worked, ' $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tourcat', array("fields" => "all")); foreach($term_list as $term_single) { echo $term_single->term_id; }' it will only output those categories that are assigned to that particular post because you are using '$post-ID' in the argument list.

Comment: Hi, if you need 'terms' as a variable, use  $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tourcat', array("fields" => "all")); and change  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tour', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'tourcat','field' => 'ID','terms' => $term_list ) ));

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$postData = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'tour',   // custom post type
    'posts_per_page'=>10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tourcat', //custom taxonomy name
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 7
        )
    )
));
if($postData->have_posts()):
    while ($postData->have_posts()): $postData->the_post();
        echo "TEST TEST TEST TEST";
        the_title();
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
        the_content();
        echo '</div>';  
    endwhile;
endif;
```